# Uniqueness of the inner-product for $L_2[a,b]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Is the standard inner-product on $L_2[a,b]$ defined as $\langle f,g \rangle=\int_a^b f(t)g(t)dt$ the only inner-product that can be defined for $L_2$?

Comment: No: $\langle f,\, g\rangle =\int_a^b{f(t)g(t)e^t\,dt}$ defines a scalar product which induces the same topology, but completely different otherwise.

Comment: Even easier: replace $e^t$ by a constant.

Comment: There can also be a conjugation on $g$.

Comment: In fact $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b f(t)\overline{g(t)}\ \mathsf dt$ is the standard inner product when functions are taken to be complex-valued.